# Confused by URLs in HUGO with Ananke

Tags: url, hugo

I am using HUGO with the [ananke](https://github.com/theNewDynamic/gohugo-theme-ananke) theme. In the main `config.yaml`, I define the `baseURL` as follows:

```
baseURL: "https://username.github.io/myblog"
```

I put some images in `static/images`. Say, I want to include the image both, as featured_image of a post and in the post itself. By trial and error, I found that the URL in the frontmatter should be

```
---
featured_image: "/images/myimage.jpg"
---
```

However, to include the image in the post body, I need to use the URL

```
[my image](/myblog/images/myimage.jpg)
```

..otherwise the effective URL will be `https://username.github.io/images/myimage.jpg`.

That does not make any sense to me. Why are the two different? Why does `[my image](/images/myimage.jpg)` not work, when `featured_image: "/images/myimage.jpg"` works? Can you explain?

First problem is that maybe one day I decide to move the site - and I don't want to have to check / replace each and every `myblog/` path. The second problem is that I would like actually to have a slightly different hierarchy, where each posts lives in its own directory, along with its media files. However, I apparently don't understand how these URLs are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post body uses Markdown rules, so by default, it just puts the URL that you indicate between the parenthesis, either absolute or relative. It does not consider `.baseURL`.

See [Markdown doc](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#images-1) for more information

To avoid this issue, you can modify [Hugo image render hook](https://gohugo.io/templates/render-hooks/#image-markdown-example) by creating a file `layouts/_default/_markup/render-image.html`, to add `.baseURL` to all your images.

Original version (this file does not exists by default, but this is the code use, according to the documentation):

```
<p class="md__image">
  <img src="{{ .Destination | safeURL }}" alt="{{ .Text }}" {{ with .Title }} title="{{ . }}"{{ end }} />
</p>
```

Modified version (you create this file and it will be used, instead of the default version):

```
<p class="md__image">
  <img src="{{ .Page.Site.BaseURL }}{{ .Destination | safeURL }}" alt="{{ .Text }}" {{ with .Title }} title="{{ . }}"{{ end }} />
</p>
```

Be careful:

- you can not access directly the `.BaseURL` param from inside the `render-image.html`, which is a specific context. You need to go through `.Page.Site`
- this render-image file is used for all images, including the images that have an absolute URL. You may want to use a check to see if the image `.Destination` starts with `//:`, `https://` or `https://`, not to add the /myblog before.